# Problema SQLITE al crear una tabla con dos Foreign Key

Tags: android, sqlite, base-de-datos

Estoy realizando un proyecto en Android con una estructura de tablas.

Pero resulta que la `db` no la crea correctamente y no consigo ver que sucede.

Se trata de 4 tablas con sus relaciones entre ellas me deja crear las tres tablas primeras pero en la tabla noches me genera un error.

```
CREATE TABLE Usuarios (Id_Usuario INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Nombre 
TEXT, Apellidos TEXT, DNI TEXT);

CREATE TABLE Dietas (Id_Dieta INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
Id_Usuario_FK INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(Id_Usuario_FK) REFERENCES 
Usuarios(Id_Usuario));

CREATE TABLE Proyectos(Id_Proyecto INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Nombre 
TEXT, Analitica TEXT);

CREATE TABLE Noches (Id_Noche INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Cantidad 
INTEGER, Id_Dieta_FK INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(Id_Dieta_FK) REFERENCES 
Dietas(Id_Dieta), Id_Proyecto_FK INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(Id_Proyecto_FK) 
REFERENCES Proyectos(Id_Proyecto));
```

Lo he ejecutado sobre el `browser` de `SQLite` y si creo la tabla Noches con una  sola `Foreign key`, cualquiera de ellas, sí que me la crea, pero si pongo las dos a la vez no, entiendo que el problema viene por ahí...

Alguien puede darme un poco de luz.

Gracias!!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Cuál es el error que arroja?

Comment: error near "Id_dieta_FK": syntax error: create TABLE Noches(Id_Noche INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Cantidad integer, Id_Proyecto_FK integer, foreign key(Id_Proyecto_FK) references Proyectos(Id_Proyecto), Id_dieta_FK

Comment: Pon en la pregunta el código tal y como lo tienes, el mensaje de error muestra el `CREATE TABLE` algo diferente al código que compartes en la pregunta.

Comment: En http://sqlfiddle.com funciona sin problemas... estás seguro que lo que estás ejecutando es exactamente lo que colocas en la pregunta ? 
tienes activadas las foreign_keys en el motor SQLITE ?

Answer (score 2):

Tenes que poner los FOREIGN KEY depués de la definición de los campos, no entremezclado con ellos:

```
CREATE TABLE Noches (
    Id_Noche INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    Cantidad INTEGER, 
    Id_Dieta_FK INTEGER, 
    Id_Proyecto_FK INTEGER, 
    FOREIGN KEY(Id_Proyecto_FK) REFERENCES Proyectos(Id_Proyecto),
    FOREIGN KEY(Id_Dieta_FK) REFERENCES Dietas(Id_Dieta)
);
```

Comment: Perfecto Juan!! Funciona perfectamente!!. Muchas gracias me estaba volviendo loco.